# We created an opportunity and expected it to have an associated task, but it didn’t. Make sure your trigger inserts the task into the database

Tags: trigger.io

We created an opportunity and expected it to have an associated task, but it didn’t. Make sure your trigger inserts the task into the database

2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
List taskListToInsert = new List();

```
    for(Opportunity opp : [Select Id,StageName from Opportunity 
                              where Id in :Trigger.New AND StageName = 'Closed Won'])
    {
            taskListtoInsert.add(new Task(Subject ='Follow Up Test Task',WhatId = opp.Id));

    }

if(taskListtoInsert.size()>0)
{
    insert taskListtoInsert;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead this line

```
 List taskListToInsert = new List();
```

try this

```
 List<Task> taskListToInsert = new List<Task>();
```

You should also check if you have any process builder activated that may be causing this problem